# Formulário com datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datapicker

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de agendamento e estou utilizando o [datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) para fazer a marcação das horas.
Preciso de um help com json; preciso bloquear as datas que estão sendo usadas para que não possam ser selecionadas. O projeto ta atualizado no github.

Desde já, agradeço!

[Projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/pedrowperez/form-datetimepicker-agenda)

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT, aconselho antes de mais nada fazer o tour no site http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Veja também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Tem que ter muita disposição pra analisar *todo* o projeto pra conseguir sugerir algum tipo de solução. Relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400977/xdsoft-datetimepicker-disable-sundays

Comment: Valeu rodorgas. Vou simplificar as coisas.

Answer (score 1):

utilize a função:

```
disabledDates   []  

Disbale all dates in list

{disabledDates: ['01.01.2014','02.01.2014','03.01.2014','04.01.2014','05.01.2014','06.01.2014'], formatDate:'d.m.Y'}
```

Ela é do próprio `datetimepicker`, ta na documentação, com ela você bloqueia os dias que você quer.
faz uma *query* para saber quais as datas não podem ser utilizadas, salva em um array e coloca assim nas opções do `datapicker`:

```
disabledDates: arrayComDatas
```